# How to navigate to href of selected a tag in access VBA

Tags: html, ms-access, dom, vba

my program gathers `<a>` tags from a website via `getElementsByTag("a")`. On the website im extracting from, each `<a>` tag has an href link. Via access VBA how to I enter that href website?

This is what I have so far

```
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim HTML As HTMLDocument
Dim b As IHTMLElement
Dim alist As IHTMLElementCollection

Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = False
ie.Navigate ("https://www.example.com")

Set HTML = ie.Document
Set ie = Nothing

Set alist = HTML.getElementsByTagName("a")

For Each b In alist

        Set ie = New InternetExplorer

Next b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call the `href` property to get the link:

```
For Each b In alist

        Set ie = New InternetExplorer
        ie.navigate b.href

        'wait for IE to load
         Do: Loop While ie.busy Or ie.readystate <> 4

Next b
```

You'll also need to add the ``wait for IE to load` part in the initial navigate call or the code will move on in execution before IE is fully loaded.

Comment: hey, after adding the "wait for IE to load call" to my initial IE navigate, my second "wait for IE call" (to navigate into the href) will cause an error: "Automation error, The object involved has disconnected from its clients"

Comment: perhaps do not use the `ie` as the variable name each time. What about use `ie` for the first website then `ie1` for each link ... or `ie1`... `ie2` etc. ... and doen't set `ie = nothing` in the beginning.

Comment: hey scott, looking back at the website's DOM, I found out that the href triggers a javascript function. I posted a second question concerning this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34138269/calling-javascript-function-from-access-vba